# Floating point numbers of Python "float" and PostgreSQL "double precision"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, floating-point

Are Python's "float" type and PostgreSQL's "double precision" type based on the same C implementation? That may not be the real underlying problem here, but anyway, here's what I get when I try to manipulate small numbers in both environments:

On Python (2.7.2 GCC 4.2.1, if that's relevant):

```
>>> float('1e-310')
1e-310
```

On PostgreSQL (9.1.1):

```
postgres# select 1e-310::double precision;
ERROR:  "0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001" is out of range for type double precision
```

What I understand is that Python float type "handles" 1e-310 while PostgreSQL double precision type does not.
Both [Python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) and [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT) docs on, respectively, "float" and "double precision" types, refer to the IEEE 754 standard, which is supposed to be implemented on "most platforms" (I'm on OS X Lion 10.7.3).

Could anyone explain what's happening here? And give me a solution, I'd like for instance to "reduce" Python precision so I can insert floats in my database through a Django FloatField. (The full use case is that I'm reading figures from a file and then inserting them).

Some (maybe interesting) additional information, in Python:

```
>>> sys.float_info
sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)
>>> 1e-320.__sizeof__()
24
```

I really don't get the second one.

Comment: I'd speculate that Postgres is refusing to give it to you because .1 can't be represented exactly in binary (for the mantissa).

Comment: @bdares I'm not sure I understand. "select 1e-100::double precision;" works fine in Postgres; and I don't think this is an exactitude issue, but rather a precision one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value float('1e-310') is a [denormal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) which is outside the usual range of exponents for 53-bit floats (+308 to -308) so it is stored with less precision in order to achieve gradual underflow.

It seems the PostgreSQL has some unresolved issues with denormals: http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2011-06/msg00885.php

For values near zero, consider rounding them prior to storage in the DB:

```
>>> round(float('1e-302'), 308)
1e-302
>>> round(float('1e-310'), 308)
0.0
```

Comment: Thank! Cool no man's land. However there's an even narrower region where your solution don't work: e.g. round(float('1e-308'), 308) gives 1e-308 which is not accepted by postgres. I simply chose to do: if abs(ff) < sys.float_info.min: ff=0. I'm surprised I seem to be the first django-postgres user on SO to fall in that zone.